# How to properly implement user authentication and authorization (FirebaseAuth with NodeJS backend)

Tags: firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm creating an app using firebase authentication and I'm still new to authentication and authorization. What I have already done is implement firebase authentication in the front end, when a user signs up successfully it will request to the backendend and verify its `idToken` firebase admin. When it's verified, the user's data will then be stored in the database together with the `uid` returned in verifying the `idToken`.

All is working but I have no clear idea on the best practices on authentication, am I on the right track? From what I've read, authenticated client should also pass a token in the header.

Should I return the `uid` to the client and use it in the header? If so, should the backend use it to check if there's a matching token in the database every client request?

I'm really quite lost with the log in flow standards, any answers are much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so the first thing to understand is that Firebase operates on a client-side paradigm, meaning that you actually don't need to and should carefully consider whether you need to conduct Firebase operations server side. In principle, you can do everything on javascript on the web browser. or Android app. or iOS app.

If you do decide to move some functions server side, next best solution is to do them as hosted cloud functions in firebase too. See:

[Callable cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

If for some reason you need to deploy and host your own code, then you can continue as you are, doing auth client side, passing the token, decoding the token with node admin, and manually checking the user permissions as applicable.